# Remove from my list items that are not in the min and max depth

Tags: java

I have a `list` that represents a tree Categories. In this list I want to keep only the value between min and max values.

***Tree Categorie:***

[image: Tree Categorie]

```
int minDepth = 1
int maxDepth = 3

Iterator<TicketCategoryType> iterator = _treeCategories.getDepths().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    TicketCategoryType value = iterator.next();
    ...
}
```

I don't know how I can implement this ?

Comment: "In this list I want to keep only the value between min and max values" -> the value of which attribute? `_nDepthNumber`? `_nId`? Also please respect Java coding conventions: Attributes should not start with an `_`, but with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's an `ArrayList`, just use [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
_treeCategories.getDepths()
    .removeIf(c -> c.getDepth() < min || c.getDepth() > max);
```

(Or `c._nDepthNumber` instead of `c.getDepth()` - just however you access the depth).

Comment: Provided OP wants to filter by `_nDepth` and not by e.g. `nId`.

Comment: ouh that solution looks much nicer! +1

Comment: @Turing85 which seems to be the case, given the title and body of the question.

Comment: @YannicKlem it's also more efficient. The thing about removing items from anything but the end of an `ArrayList` is that all following elements have to shifted. This means that repeatedly calling `Iterator.remove()` yields a quadratic algorithm. `removeIf` does it linearly, by deferring all of the "shifting" until the very end.

Comment: @AndyTurner "Implementation Requirements:
    The default implementation traverses all elements of the collection using its iterator(). Each matching element is removed using Iterator.remove(). If the collection's iterator does not support removal then an UnsupportedOperationException will be thrown on the first matching element." That's the doc of Collection.removeIf ;) It's exactly the same in the end but with less code

Comment: @YannicKlem right: that's the *default* implementation, *not* [`ArrayList`'s implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#1393).

Answer (score 1):

You could call `iterator.remove()` to remove the element the iterator points on.

Assuming that by

> the value between min and max values.

you mean that `_nDepthNumber` should be greater or equal to 1 and lower or equal to 3 the code would like this:

```
int minDepth = 1
int maxDepth = 3

Iterator<TicketCategoryType> iterator = _treeCategories.getDepths().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  TicketCategoryType value = iterator.next();
  if(!(value._nDepthNumber >= minDepth && value._nDepthNumber <= maxDepth) {
    iterator.remove();
  }
}
```

It hurts a bit to violate java coding conventions like this. Please don't use underscores as prefix for variables.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to use stream filter:

```
_treeCategories.getDepths().stream()
        .filter(ticketCategoryType -> ticketCategoryType.depth > minDepth && ticketCategoryType.depth < maxDepth)
        .forEach(ticketCategoryType -> System.out.println(ticketCategoryType.depth));
```

Here is a runnable example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EliminationInLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int minDepth = 1;
        int maxDepth = 3;

        TreeCategory _treeCategories = new TreeCategory();
        _treeCategories.add(new TicketCategoryType(2));
        _treeCategories.add(new TicketCategoryType(4));
        _treeCategories.add(new TicketCategoryType(1));
        _treeCategories.getDepths().stream()
                .filter(ticketCategoryType -> ticketCategoryType.depth > minDepth && ticketCategoryType.depth < maxDepth)
                .forEach(ticketCategoryType -> System.out.println(ticketCategoryType.depth));
    }

    private static class TicketCategoryType {

        private final int depth;

        private TicketCategoryType(int depth) {
            this.depth = depth;
        }
    }

    private static class TreeCategory {

        private List<TicketCategoryType> depths = new ArrayList<>();

        public TreeCategory() {
        }

        public List<TicketCategoryType> getDepths() {
            return depths;
        }

        public boolean add(TicketCategoryType ticketCategoryType) {
            return depths.add(ticketCategoryType);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
2
```